# Get YouTube channel information with Google API in Java

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-api

Currently I'm using this code from this google link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix=true

```html
/**
 * Sample Java code for youtube.subscriptions.list
 * See instructions for running these code samples locally:
 * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#java
 */

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SubscriptionListResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ApiExample {
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS= "MY_CLIENT_SECRET.json";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "YouTube Bridge";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Create an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
          GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .build();
        Credential credential =
            new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    }

    /**
     * Call function to create API service object. Define and
     * execute API request. Print API response.
     *
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();
        // Define and execute the API request
        YouTube.Subscriptions.List request = youtubeService.subscriptions()
            .list("");
        SubscriptionListResponse response = request.execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

I added my "client_secret.json" and changed the channel id a few times.
But I have two problems with the code:

1. Every time I run this program I have to log in with a google account. Is this necessary?
2. With every id I try I get a 403 action forbidden error. Why? Do I have to authorize myself somewhere?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code we need to see your full login flow and how you are making the calls to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code in my question doesn't work I just used an HTTP request to get the data.

```html
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class http
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String id = "CHANNEL_ID";
        String key = "YOUR_API_KEY";

        String query = String.format("id=%s&key=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(id, charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(key, charset));

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "&" + query).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response)) {
            String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
    }
}
```

The string responseBody then contains all the data from the channel to work with.